# Tor proxy issues?

Tags: proxy

I am having some trouble connecting with Tor. This what I get:

```
07/11/2016 20:11:23.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
07/11/2016 20:11:23.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
07/11/2016 20:11:23.900 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
07/11/2016 20:11:23.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
07/11/2016 20:11:25.100 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
07/11/2016 20:13:46.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
07/11/2016 20:13:47.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop3' (fresh): $8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E~ndnop3 at 109.105.109.165 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.000 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop5' (fresh): $BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D~ndnop5 at 109.105.109.147 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'noether' (fresh): $7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2~noether at 192.99.11.54 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'riemann' (fresh): $752CF7825B3B9EA6A98C83AC41F7099D67007EA5~riemann at 198.245.60.50 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.700 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Azadi' (fresh): $FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D~Azadi at 154.35.22.13 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.700 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'JonbesheSabz' (fresh): $00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB~JonbesheSabz at 154.35.22.12 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.700 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Mosaddegh' (fresh): $8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55~Mosaddegh at 154.35.22.10 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'GreenBelt' (fresh): $C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716~GreenBelt at 154.35.22.9 
07/11/2016 20:13:48.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'MaBishomarim' (fresh): $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637~MaBishomarim at 154.35.22.11 
07/11/2016 20:13:52.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'LeifEricson' (fresh): $A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239~LeifEricson at 83.212.101.3 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.600 [WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options. 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.600 [WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options. 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] Bridge at '158.69.14.73:5197' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6) 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] Bridge at '194.132.209.34:51929' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6) 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] Bridge at '77.81.104.251:443' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6) 
07/11/2016 20:46:37.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
07/11/2016 20:46:44.300 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

I do not really understand what is reachable adresses and what to do. 
Please! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you configure Tor Browser you get to specify if you can only access specific IP or Ports. In this case the set of IP and Ports you've specified being able to access excludes all of the bridges defined.

To configure this to go the Green Onion button, select Tor Network Settings and either untick or reconfigure the 'This computer goes through a firewall...' option to accurately reflect where you can connect to.

Comment: I unticked this option. Plus I do not have any proxy or firewall activated in my computer. There is still the same error message... I really don't get what's wrong...

Comment: Can you see what your `torrc` file contains? If you're still getting `[WARN] Tor cannot connect to the Internet if ReachableAddresses, ReachableORAddresses, or ReachableDirAddresses reject all addresses. Please accept some addresses in these options.` then it's still set somewhere. It may be worth restarting Tor Browser after you've untick it.

Comment: Hello! Well the situation has changed. This what I get now : 08/11/2016 21:43:32.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
08/11/2016 21:43:32.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
08/11/2016 21:43:32.600 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
08/11/2016 21:43:32.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
08/11/2016 21:43:34.700 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. But I still have the same issue. Vidalia has indicated me that it is trying to reach a relay but it is not working.

Comment: `Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.` this says you successfully reached your guard and built a circuit.